# How to get third Thursday of last month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My report generator should get all entries  from third Thursday of last month. 
How can I achieve This in ms sql server ?

Comment: Please , show simple data , required outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
WHERE DATEPART(dw,[YourDateColumn]) = 5              -- Thursday
 AND DATEPART(d,[YourDateColumn]) BETWEEN 15 AND 21  -- Third thursday in month
 AND DATEDIFF(m,GETDATE(),[YourDateColumn])=-1       -- Last month
```

But you need to be aware that the query could be slow because of the functions.
See also: [Avoid Using Function in WHERE Clause. Why?](https://msbiskills.com/2015/06/19/avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-why/)

Answer (score 0):

For something like this is so much easier with a calender table.  See

[Create a calender date table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

The code below finds the third Thursday of last month 
(last = previous or last = current? if last = current, substitute dateadd (month, -1, getdate()) with getdate()).

You can wrap it into a function and use in WHERE clause of your query 
or calculate it just before filtering using a variable,
so your query will look like

```
SELECT...WHERE dt >= fn()
```

or

```
SELECT...WHERE dt >= @dt
option(recompile)
```

So indexes(if any) can be used

```
with nums as -- numbers 1..31
(
select number as n
from master..spt_values
where type = 'p'
and number between 0 and 30
)


, thur as
(
select dt,
       dd,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dt) as rn
from nums cross apply 
                    (
                    select cast(convert(char(6), dateadd (month, -1, getdate()), 112) + '01' as date) as dt0 -- the first of last month
                    )a
          cross apply( select dateadd(day, n, dt0) as dt) a1
          cross apply( select datename(dw, dt) as dd, month(dt) as mm) a2
where dd = 'Thursday' and mm = month(dt0) 
)

select dt
from thur
where rn = 3;
```